# Can a noun function as an adverbial?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adverbials

As we know, some noun phrases can function as adverbials (especially temporal noun phrases). Here is an example taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial#The_form_of_adverbials):

- James answered this morning.

Can a single noun function as an adverbial? Nouns like "home" or "tomorrow" can function as adverbials, but they are also labelled as adverbs in many dictionaries. So we must find a "pure" noun.

If a noun with plural ending functions as an adverbial, this example can be regarded as a convincing example. (Except some special "plurals", for example "Sundays", which are labelled as adverbs in dictionaries)

Comment: The original construct was genitive not plural for the adverb, but it has since often been re-interpreted as a plural. See also *once, twice, thrice*.

Comment: Never use a dictionary for parts of speech. Dictionaries are great at meanings and awful at grammar!

Comment: I think you're confusing category and function. Noun is a category (part of speech) and adjunct (adverbial) is a function. Dictionaries are notorious at confusing 'category' and 'function'. "Sunday" is unarguably a noun, so in _I always visit her on Sundays_ "Sundays" is a noun and the PP "on Sundays" is an adjunct (adverbial). There you have it!

Answer (score 3):

English doesn't like to use prepositions before words like [last, next, this](http://afsha-englishforengineers.blogspot.kr/2011/06/omission-of-prepositions.html) or every. It is evident when you contrast

> I go to church on every Sunday.

with

> I go to church every Sunday.

There is no reason to use the preposition "on" in the above example. This [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+every+Sunday&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20every%20Sunday%3B%2Cc0) shows a declining trend of using "on every Sunday"

The reason why *Sundays* is listed as an adverb (in some dictionaries) is it is very broadly used in place of "on Sundays" and it functions as if it were an adverb.

However, I don't think these nouns are adverbs. They are [adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) and they are used to complement prepositions. Even if a preposition is omitted, there is no change in their meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem:

> They leave Sunday.

*Sunday* is a temporal adjunct here (read adverbial). It is a noun phrase consisting of a single noun.

Comment: Yup, +1 from me.